# Is there a limit to the number of objects an Array of ParseObject can hold?

Tags: java, android, parse-server

I have more than 153 objects stored in a parse server class called "HSK1". I want to display all the objects in a ListView but the below code only display 100 elements. Why is that?

I've checked the size of the array it only stores 100 objects.

```
ListView hsk1List;
CustomWordListAdapter adapter;
ArrayList<HskModel> words = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_hsk1);
    setTitle("HSK1 List");


    hsk1List = findViewById(R.id.hsk1List);
    adapter = new CustomWordListAdapter(words, getApplicationContext());

    //Filling the ListView-
    final ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("HSK1");
    query.addAscendingOrder("identifiant");

    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
            if(e == null){

                if(objects.size() > 0){

                    for(ParseObject object : objects){
                        words.add(new HskModel(object.get("identifiant").toString(),
                                object.get("character").toString(),
                                "(" + object.get("pinyin").toString()+ ")",
                                object.get("meaning").toString()));
                    }

                    hsk1List.setAdapter(adapter);

                    Log.i("WORDMAX", String.valueOf(objects.size()));
                }

            }else{
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

I expect output of 153 objects displayed in a list view but only 100 are stored in the array " objects "

Comment: As the Result contains only 100 items the error must be in the ParseQuery or on the server you are searching. Maybe an implicit limit to 100 items is added.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the problem was that the default query limit is set to 100 objects. If that could help someone else. There is an implicit limit of 100

Comment: The limit can be changed by using the `query.limit(anyNumber)` function.